# How to send messages to server after having connected to a websocket as client using kdb+ q

Tags: websocket, kdb

I am building a websocket client in q with the aim of connecting to cryptocurrency exchanges to receive public market data feeds in json for parsing into kdb.  At this point, using [this guide from KX's official knowledge base](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/websockets/#simple-websocket-client-example), I have managed to create a persistent websocket connection from my q process to the Kraken exchange by using stunnel as verified by a successful connection/upgrade response.  My q script just defines .z.ws to show incoming messages, then connects to my local port running stunnel.

```
.z.ws:{0N!.j.k(x);}

h:(`:ws://127.0.0.1:5103)"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ws.kraken.com\r\n\r\n"
```

My stunnel configuration looks like this:

[kraken]
client = yes
sni = ws.kraken.com
accept = 127.0.0.1:5103
connect = 104.16.212.191:443

It all seems to work because as mentioned before, my q process receives the following successfull system status confirmation.

```
`connectionID`event`status`version!(9.223372e+18;"systemStatus";"online";"1.7.2")
```

The guide says "If successful it will return a 2-item list of (handle;HTTP response)" which I also do recieve.  They look like this:

```
(6i ;"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nDate: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 22:52:53 GMT\r\nConnection: upgrade\r\nSet-Cookie: __cfduid=d8179f7ef5db4e4e7a164dd75a492c2141612824773; expires=Wed, 10-Mar-21 22:52:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.kraken.com;HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=\r\nuWebSockets:17\r\nCF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC\r\ncf-request-id: 082..)
```

I really thought that would be the tough part and I'm feeling somewhat proud to have succeeded thus far, but now I'm finding myself stuck again.

**How do I interact with the websocket now? I want to send more messages ie. subscribe/unsubscribe to specific endpoints?**

The guide cited above says very clearly "To send messages, use

```
q)neg[handle]"text" / a char vector"
```

but whenever I try

```
q)neg[6i].j.j(`ping)
```

I get the following error

```
'Cannot write to handle 6. OS reports: Bad file descriptor
```

I suspect maybe I need to subscribe to certain endpoints somehow in my initial GET request, but I'd still like to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe from different endpoints freely after having connected to the websocket.

Thanks for reading, and any insight is much appreciated.  This is my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Best Regards,
Ross

Comment: Interestingly, I've found that the error does not happen if I send the subscribe message as part of the original script.  When I try to subscribe in q after having connected to the socket, I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

That error could be related to your message getting rejected. I had a quick look at the python example and it looks to expect json like this:

```
{"event": "ping"}

So you'd need to send something like this:

q).j.j(1#`event)!1#`ping
"{\"event\":\"ping\"}"
```

https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022327631-WebSocket-API-Public-Feeds-Python-Code-Examples

Aqua Q has a Crypto add-on for their TorQ kdb framework which could be useful:

https://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/torq-crypto-released/

https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ-Crypto

(Disclaimer, I work for Aqua Q)

Comment: Thanks Matt!  This was very helpful and has definitely helped me bridge the gap between that kraken literature and my q process.  I've been able to get it to work as desired by sending messages inside my original web socket client connection script, but I'm still not exactly sure how to do it after the websocket connection has already been established because the same error happens.  I suspect it has something to do with my stunnel setup but its not actually a big deal because I'm having success scripting what I want to do anyhow.  ALSO, thanks for the heads up on tor-q.  I'm looking into it.